# VBScript regex for splitting email

Tags: regex, email, vbscript

I am given a single line of string like this

```
To: =?ks_c_5601-1987?B?vcW5zsHY?= <test1@test.co.kr>,
    =?ks_c_5601-1987?B?wNO9w8ij?= <test2@gmail.com>, Henry Han
    <test3@hotmail.com>
```

Basically, they are sets of email addresses encoded in a certain character set.

I'd like to split them up and have an array just containing the email address

EX:

```
toAddress(0) = test1@test.co.kr
toAddress(1) = test2@gmail.com
toAddress(2) = test3@hotmail.com
```

Is VBScript's regex function versatile enough to get what I need above? I'd appreciate any guidance, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
dim regex:set regex=new RegExp
regex.Global=True
regex.IgnoreCase=True
regex.Pattern="<.*?>"
dim ori:ori="To: =?ks_c_5601-1987?B?vcW5zsHY?= <test1@test.co.kr>," & vbLF &_
    "=?ks_c_5601-1987?B?wNO9w8ij?= <test2@gmail.com>, Henry Han " & vbLF &_
    "<test3@hotmail.com>"
Response.Write ori & vbLF 'just for debug
dim matches:set matches=regex.Execute(ori)
For Each match In matches
    Response.Write match.value & vbLF
Next
```

Tested with IIS 5, outputs:

```
<test1@test.co.kr>
<test2@gmail.com>
<test3@hotmail.com>
```

You can remove the `<` and `>` when fetching `match.Value`.